# EX4 ActionScript and a minus symbol

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, e4x

I have a XML node with a `-` (minus) character in it. How can I access this in ActionScript E4X symtax without the compiler recognising the character as a minus operator?

E.g.

*XML*

```
<page>
     <about-page>yo</about-page>
</page>
```

*ActionScript*

```
this.contentXML..page.about-page.text()
```

Thanks,
Ross

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use the [child](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/XML.html#child()) notation as well.

Comment: Thanks, I'm this method as correct as it also work with the double dot notation.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use the square bracket notation for accessing the property:

```
this.contentXML.page['about-page'].text()
```

Both the dot and square bracket notation do essentially the same thing, that is looking up a property. The only difference here is that the dot notation is limited by the syntax of the language.